# Moving django app from virtualenv site-packages folder to projects root directory

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv, django-apps

New to django… i'm wondering if there is a way to move an app which i installed with pip in virtualenvs site-packages folder to my projects root directory. 
I ask this because in my current case i'm using django-cms aldryn-blog and if i modify it's data in site-packages my changes wont be deployed because on server i install everything with pip from requirements. So i think the best would be to take the site-packages i want to modify to my project root directory because this way i wont forget about them when i deploy my site.
Is this clever and how could i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, an it is a normal thing to do. Just copy the folder from site-packages or download it directly on PyPI or GitHub. Don't forget to add the apps to the settings.

Comment: thanks a lot guys sooo simple couldnt imagine <3 django

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe just download it from github? 
https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-blog

And remove it from requirements of course, put it somewhere in your app directory or home directory and change the path in your INSTALLED_APPS accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can have it both ways:

1. Download the entire package to where it is most convenient for you to work on.
2. Install it in development/editable mode using `pip install -e dirname` (where dirname is the directory containing `setup.py`).

This will crete a `.pth` file in site-packages pointing to where you put your sources. You can do this in your `requirements.txt` file too (`-e path/to/package`).